# how do I debug my PHP code in Netbeans?

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, remote-debugging

I am just beginning my journey into PHP world and I chose Netbeans editor. I am using the latest one i.e V7.0.1 and setup WAMP. However, I don't quiet understand how will I debug my PHP code? My breakpoints don't get hit in Netbeans.

Any help would be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Read about [Xdebug Remote Debugging](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote), this integrates with NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to debugging, learn how to profile your code with XDEBUG. You can configure Xdebug so there is a switch ?XDEBUG_PROFILE added to your URL, which will record the precise time of each statement. Install webgrind to see detailed reports in your browser. WAMP may already have it installed, just look in your PHP.INI file. If not visit the XDEBUG site.

Learn how to write efficient code from the start :)

Answer (score 0):

See this document: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Or more generally, the PHP Learning Trail: http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html